# Angular 8 Routing, changes route on the browser but doesnt load component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Trying to understand the whole routing fuse in Angular 8.2.14, I converted a bootstrap template to angular separating each components like the header and side menu etc.
I added these into the app.components.html like this

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-sidemenu></app-sidemenu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and in the app-routing.module.ts like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/site/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AllStudentsComponent } from './students/all-students/all-students.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'all-students', component: AllStudentsComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts looks like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/layout/header/header.component';
import { SidemenuComponent } from './components/layout/sidemenu/sidemenu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/layout/footer/footer.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/site/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { CustomiserComponent } from './components/layout/customiser/customiser.component';
import { AllStudentsComponent } from './students/all-students/all-students.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidemenuComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    CustomiserComponent,
    AllStudentsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now when I serve the app for the first time it navigates to dashboard flawlessly, however when I try to navigate to ./all-students it changes on the browser tab but doesn't load the all-students component until I refresh from the browser then it loads, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The setup looks fine. Do you get any errors in the console?
Could you show some code from your AllStudentsComponent?

Comment: Here is simplified example for routing you can try compare what you do different 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-89dfck

Comment: @hlfrmn AllStudentsComponent is actually empty, problem is, it doesn't load the concerned component when I click using the links on the side menu but loads when I refresh it directly because it changes the link on the browser but doesn't load the associated component